# How to transform XML input with multiple identical elements into XML output without identical elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I tried to transform an xml input file that contains multiple identical elements into a new xml file that will combine all identical elements into one. The input file is like is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<InputShipmentSchedule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<DataArea>
    <ShipmentSchedule>
        <ShipmentScheduleLine>
            <ManufacturingItem>
                <ItemID>
                    <ID>P313503</ID>
                </ItemID>
            </ManufacturingItem>                
        </ShipmentScheduleLine>
        <ShipmentScheduleLine>
            <ManufacturingItem>
                <ItemID>
                    <ID>P313503</ID>
                </ItemID>
            </ManufacturingItem>            
        </ShipmentScheduleLine>
        <ShipmentScheduleLine>
            <ManufacturingItem>
                <ItemID>
                    <ID>P313504</ID>
                </ItemID>
            </ManufacturingItem>            
        </ShipmentScheduleLine>
        <ShipmentScheduleLine>
            <ManufacturingItem>
                <ItemID>
                    <ID>P313504</ID>
                </ItemID>
            </ManufacturingItem>            
        </ShipmentScheduleLine>
    </ShipmentSchedule>
</DataArea>
</InputShipmentSchedule>
```

I made the following xsl transformer file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="InputShipmentSchedule">
    <xsl:call-template name="CreateShipmentScheduleXmlns"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="CreateShipmentScheduleXmlns">
    <xsl:element name="Output_Data">
        <xsl:element name="ShipmentSchedule">
                <xsl:call-template name="part_detail_template">
                    <xsl:with-param name="currentPartLine" select="DataArea/ShipmentSchedule/ShipmentScheduleLine"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="nextPartLine" select="DataArea/ShipmentSchedule/ShipmentScheduleLine/following-sibling::ShipmentScheduleLine"/>
                </xsl:call-template>                
        </xsl:element>  <!-- ShipmentSchedule tag end -->
    </xsl:element>  <!-- Output_Data tag end -->
</xsl:template> <!-- CreateShipmentScheduleXmlns template end -->

<xsl:template name="part_detail_template">
    <xsl:param name="currentPartLine"/>
    <xsl:param name="nextPartLine"/>
    <xsl:element name="Part_Detail">  <!-- Part_Detail tag start -->
        <xsl:variable name="part_no" select="$currentPartLine/ManufacturingItem/ItemID/ID"/>
        <xsl:element name="part_no">
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="$part_no"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>  <!-- Part_Detail tag end -->
    <xsl:variable name="currentItem" select="$currentPartLine/ManufacturingItem/ItemID/ID"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nextItem" select="$nextPartLine/ManufacturingItem/ItemID/ID"/>
    <xsl:choose>            
        <xsl:when test="$nextPartLine and $nextItem != $currentItem">
            <xsl:call-template name="part_detail_template">
                <xsl:with-param name="currentPartLine" select="$nextPartLine"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="nextPartLine" select="$nextPartLine/following-sibling::ShipmentScheduleLine"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>  <!-- part_detail_template tag end -->                                        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output xml file still contains redundant P313503 as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Output_Data>
<ShipmentSchedule>
<Part_Detail>
<part_no value="P313503"/>
</Part_Detail>
<Part_Detail>
<part_no value="P313503"/>
</Part_Detail>
<Part_Detail>
<part_no value="P313504"/>
</Part_Detail>
</ShipmentSchedule>
</Output_Data>
```

I don't know why the "part_no" element ("P313503") would appear twice. It is supposed to contain non-redundant "part_no" element in the output xml file. What did I do wrong in the above xsl file? Any comment or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                <xsl:with-param name="currentPartLine" 
                select="DataArea/ShipmentSchedule/ShipmentScheduleLine"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="nextPartLine" 
                select="DataArea/ShipmentSchedule/ShipmentScheduleLine/
                                   following-sibling::ShipmentScheduleLine"/>
```

These two expressions select the same node set. `DataArea/ShipmentSchedule/ShipmentScheduleLine` selects *all* the `ShipmentScheduleLine` elements not just the first, and so adding `following-sibling::ShipmentScheduleLine` does not select any different nodes.

Grouping problems are a lot easier in XSLT2 than XSLT1 but assuming you are stuck at 1 for some reason. google for "muenchian grouping" which will lead you to this solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="n" match="ItemID" use="ID"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <Output_Data>
  <ShipmentSchedule>
   <xsl:for-each select="//ManufacturingItem/ItemID[generate-id()=
             generate-id(key('n',.))]">
    <Part_Detail>
     <part_no value="{.}"/>
    </Part_Detail>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </ShipmentSchedule>
 </Output_Data>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which produces:

```
$ saxon man.xml man.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Output_Data>
   <ShipmentSchedule>
      <Part_Detail>
         <part_no value="P313503"/>
      </Part_Detail>
      <Part_Detail>
         <part_no value="P313504"/>
      </Part_Detail>
   </ShipmentSchedule>
</Output_Data>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how do I make the first expression to select just the first node, not all the ShipmentScheduleLine? I tried "DataArea/ShipmentSchedule/ShipmentScheduleLine/.". It did not remove the redundant "part_no" element ("P313503") in the output xml file.

Comment: DataArea/ShipmentSchedule/ShipmentScheduleLine[1] will select the first

Comment: as noted in the comment adding numeric predicates would probably make it work but repeatedly searching the full path is inefficient anyway, and it's better to use a different grouping idiom, see updated answer

Comment: Great! Your suggested "muenchian grouping" works to meet my requirement. Thanks a lot, David.